# BQ Date_ADD bug

Tags: google-bigquery

I notice that if i minus 5 hours with date_add function - it's not take the date one day back 
if it's should like this example

however if i wrapped it with date function so than it's showing the correct date.

```
select 
DATE_ADD(timestamp('2014-10-26 04:00:00'), -5, "HOUR") as est_timstamp,
date(DATE_ADD(timestamp('2014-10-26 04:00:00'), -5, "HOUR")) as est_date
```

I will be glade to hear how can use Date_Add and still remain with timestamp type
and the day is moving back.

Answer (score 2):

OK I think I know what is happening.

The query is returning a UTC timestamp. However, the BigQuery Web UI is rendering that timestamp in your timezone. One way to get around this would be to cast the timestamp to a string.

Comment: if you run this select timestamp('2014-10-25 23:00:00') do you get 2014-10-25 23:00:00? i'm getting  2014-10-26 23:00:01 UTC

Comment: I believe I've figured out what is going on. It is a UI display issue.

Comment: Aviv, can you share what browser and OS you are running?  This will help us to debug the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: i'm using mac os, but it's happen also on on my server